# npm mail-listener2: Attachments are not saved from Outlook 2016

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, protractor

I am trying to download the attachments from Outlook, in a specified folder as defined in configuration:

```
    {
        username: "username@here",
        password: "password",
        host: "hostName",
        port: 993,
        connTimeout: 10000,
        authTimeout: 5000,
        //debug: console.log,
        tls: true,
        tlsOptions: {rejectUnauthorized: false},
        mailbox: "INBOX",
        searchFilter: ["UNSEEN"],
        markSeen: true,
        fetchUnreadOnStart: true,
        mailParserOptions: {streamAttachments: true},
        attachments: true,
        attachmentOptions: {directory: downloadPath, stream: "true"}
    }
```

downloadPath is one of the locations in local project directory

while the email read function is working fine and is writing the content of email on the console, however, the Attachment Path appears as undefined and nothing gets saved in the defined folder.

(I have tried "attachments/" as well but nothing works)

```
  {
    ...
    ...

    mailListener.on("attachment", function(attachment){
        console.log("Attachment Path: " + attachment.path);
  });
```

My final goal is to download the attachment in a predefined folder and read the pdf content of the file through pdf reader package.

Console log output:

```
@ReadEmail
Scenario: Read email from outlook
√ Given User has access to outlook
√ When User tries to access the new email in the Outlook
- Then User should be able to read the email and save attachments
Mail listener initialized
Attachment Path: undefined
Date: 2018-02-23T01:57:43.000Z
Subject: Test Email with attachment
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I was using the reference to incorrect parent folder:

Previous:

```
attachmentOptions: {directory: path.join(__dirname,'attachments/')}
```

updated to:

```
attachmentOptions: {directory: path.join(__dirname,'\\attachments/')}
```

working fine now, thanks